# sql lite change 41934 to 22 10 2014

Tags: sqlite

I need to change change "41934" to 22-10-2014.
"41934"is located in [Leverdatum]

i always use

```
"update bron set [collumname]"
```

in the start of an SQL conversion or for an exeption where i need to delete somthing (like empty rows) i use

```
"delete from bron where"
```

In excel you only have to change the cellularity from standard to date.
to bad it isn't that easy in SQLite.

could someone help me?

greets jasper

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking about how to convert from `41934` to `22-10-2014`? Why use `DELETE`? By what schema and/or algorithm is `41934` equal to `22-10-2014`?

Comment: Yes, If i look online i see many times 'select' and that kind of things, I dont need 'delete' i think i was just saying. that i till now only have used these two sql-conversions. thx for fast response

Comment: I still don't understand your question. Please describe what you want to do, what you have tried, if it works, what errors you get.

Comment: I  need to change change "41934" to "22-10-2014". I Have tried "update bron set [Leverdatum] = date([Leverdatum], 'unixepoch')

Comment: What format is `41934`? *Why* is it 22nd of October 2014?

Comment: Also: " update bron set [Leverdatum] = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', [Leverdatum]) and a few other things. Nothoing works otherwise wouldn't ask it. No errors [Leverdatum] somethimes was empty but that was most of the time the sql-conversion was not right.

Comment: @Tichodroma, I believe it is Excel's concept of the epoch:  January 0th, 1900 (rather, 31-Dec-1899).  GNU date confirms (`date -d '41934 days ago'`), and see also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

Comment: @Tichodroma I don't know. If i enter "41934" in excel and than go to cellurity and sellect "date" where it was before "standard" it changes to 22-10-2014

Comment: Excel interprets the `41934` as the number of days since 01-01-1900. I don't know any SQLite function that does the same.

Comment: @Tichodroma unixepoch is that only it is in seconds not days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To interpret 41934 as an offset measured in days from 31-Dec-1899, use sqlite's [date and time](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) functions:

```
sqlite> select date('1899-12-31', '+' || 41934 || ' days');
```

or in your case:

```
update bron set [Leverdatum] = date('1899-12-31', '+' || [Leverdatum] || ' days');
```